# Copy info and then count not NULL, Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, count, null

I have a piece of code to copy some info out of a random number of sheets (from the 7th sheet and on). as follows

```
Sub Controle()

Dim sh As Worksheet, N As Long
Dim i As Long, M As Long
N = Sheets.Count
M = 1
For i = 7 To N
    Sheets(i).Range("E2").Copy
    Sheets("Controle tabel").Cells(1, M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
    Sheets("Controle tabel").Cells(1, M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
    M = M + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

I also want to count the amount on values in column A, I tried to add this

```
Sheets(i).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

but it won't run, I think I need to add how where to paste it, since it has to come under the names pasted using the code but I have no clue how this can ben done. I added a new variable L to make a list just as with M

```
Sheets(i).Range("A:A").Cells(1, L).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

But it still won't run I think I might be using the wrong way to count no null (since you also have COUNTA, but since we don't know the names of the sheets this is hard I think)

So it also has to loop all the sheets after the 7th and count the not empty cells in column A

Comment: What do you mean by "won't run"? If you get an error message, what is it? Your first formulation looks ok to me, your second is only checking one cell (assuming L has a positive value).

Comment: it is giving me method is not supported by this object

Comment: Have you assigned that value to a cell, e.g. `Sheets("Controle tabel").Cells(1,1)=Sheets(i).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count`? On its own it won't work as it's not doing anything.

Comment: `Dim i As Long, M As Long, L As Long` So as long, just as the other ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing a little, but this?

```
Sub Controle()

Dim sh As Worksheet, N As Long
Dim i As Long, M As Long, L As Long
N = Sheets.Count
M = 1
For i = 7 To N
    Sheets(i).Range("E2").Copy
    Sheets("Controle tabel").Cells(1, M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
    Sheets("Controle tabel").Cells(1, M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
    Sheets("Controle tabel").Cells(1, M + 1) = Sheets(i).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    M = M + 2
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I did make it to paste next to each other that is handy I figured  `Dim sh As Worksheet, N As Long
    Dim i As Long, M As Long
    N = Sheets.Count
    M = 2
    For i = 7 To N
        Sheets(i).Range("E2").Copy
        Sheets("Controle tabel").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial (xlValues)
        Sheets("Controle tabel").Range("A" & M).PasteSpecial (xlFormats)
        Sheets("Controle tabel").Range("B" & M) = Sheets(i).Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
    M = M + 1

    Next i
End Sub`

Comment: If you wanted it underneath the other figure, replace "Cells(1,M+1)" with "Cells(2,M)" and change M increment back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once -

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, N, i, m, lastrow, nullcount As Long
N = Sheets.Count

For i = 7 To N

lastrow = Sheets("Controle tabel").Range("A500000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheets("Controle tabel").Range("A" & lastrow).Value = Sheets(i).Range("E2").Value

Next i
On Error Resume Next

nullcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Controle tabel").Range("A:A"), "NULL")

Sheets("Controle tabel").Range("A" & lastrow).Value = nullcount
```